# In which format have I to return data to vue-tables-2 with Server Table

Tags: vuejs2, vue-tables-2

In my vue/cli 4 / Bootstrap 4.3 app I use vue-tables-2 and reading Server Table
implementation here https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/server-table

from server side(laravel 6) I return :

```
        return response()->json([
            'data'                 => $activityLogs,
            'count'                => $activity_logs_count
        ], 200);
```

and in console I see returned data : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TctrK.jpg

```
But in the console I have errors :
vue-tables-2: invalid 'count' property. Expected number, got undefined
...
set-data.js?7175:11 count equals undefined
...
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: props.data.forEach is not a function"
...
found in
---> <RLTableBody>
       <VtTableBody>

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: props.data.forEach is not a function
    at _default (VtTableBody.js?1a4e:36)
```

I suppose that problem in format of returned data.
In vue file I have :

```
        <div id="activity_logs_data_table">
            <v-server-table :url="apiUrl + '/activity-logs-filter'" :columns="columns" :options="tableOptions">
            </v-server-table>
        </div>
   ...

                tableOptions: {
                    // see the options API
                    requestFunction(data) {

                        this.is_page_loaded = false
                        let credentialsConfig= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settingCredentialsConfig))
                        credentialsConfig.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + this.$parent.$parent.currentLoggedUserToken
                        return axios.get(this.url, {
                            params: data
                        }, credentialsConfig ).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log('requestFunction error::')
                            console.error(error)
                        })

                    } // requestFunction: (data) => {
                },
...

"axios": "^0.19.0",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-tables-2": "^2.0.14"
```

Which must be valid format for returned data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message. Was able to resolve it by modifying the response:

```
    requestFunction: function (data) {
      return this.$http
        .post(this.url, data)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          this.dispatch('error', e)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you have 401 error with bearer token in request?
I asked the developer
https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2/issues/826
and failed. Had to remove this component...